# Python Dict, Lambda x, map() doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, lambda

I'm trying to re-label/combine my market labels by using the following code. However, everything just runs through super fast, and no mapping is actually happening but just returns me the original columns. Company is the table name, and company.market is the column of market. Company is a dataframe, and pandas and numpy are imported.

```
Eg. company_name market          value
    'AA'         'Bio-Pharm'     $1,000
    'BB'         'Biotechnology' $2,000
```

I'd like to relabel Company AA's market to 'Biothchnology' using my code...

```
market_mapping = {
'Bio-Pharm': 'Biotechnology',
'Biomass Power Generation': 'Biotechnology',
'Bioinformatics': 'Biotechnology',
'Biometrics': 'Biotechnology',
'Biotechnology and Semiconductor': 'Biotechnology',
'Biofuels':'Biotechnology'}

f = lambda x: market_mapping.get(x,x)
company.market = company.market.map(f)
```

Could you help me on what's wrong here? Appreciate your help in advance :)

Comment: What is `company` and what is `company.market`?

Comment: `company.market` what is this variable?

Comment: @EllieZhao: I gather from your question that `company` is a pandas DataFrame.  Is that correct?  If so, you need to say that.  There is no such thing as a "table" in plain Python.  In general if your question relates to the use of some library you need to mention that.

Comment: You really need to give a simple reproducible example-- something that someone can copy and paste to test.  From your original code, where you were trying to add a new column `market2`, I thought the problem was the use of dot syntax-- but you've changed it to `company.market`.  Now, I'm wondering if your `market` column contains leading and trailing apostrophes, or if that's just what you're using to say that they're strings.

Comment: OK the question has changed a lot since I first saw it.

Answer (score 0):

The `company` is a dataframe and `market` is an object but not a string yet.
I modified the code to:

```
f = lambda x: market_mapping.get(str(x),x)
```

And the code works!